# How do I increase the stack size using g++ with WSL? (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Command line I think should work: `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wl,-z,stack-size=1000000000 C.cc && ./a.out < C.2`
Instead of working, it segfaults. `-fsanitize=address` identifies the problem as a stack overflow.

I found https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/633 which suggests `sudo prlimit --stack=unlimited --pid $$; ulimit -s unlimited` which "works"; `ulimit -s` now prints "unlimited". But I still get the segfault. I expected the linker options above to work, but they don't. I also tried using setrlimit within the C++ code directly:

```
  struct rlimit rl;
  assert(0 == getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl));
  rl.rlim_cur = 3LL*1024*1024*1024;
  assert(0 == setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl));
  assert(0 == getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl));
  cerr << rl.rlim_cur << endl;
```

The last line prints 3GB, but I still get the stack overflow.

The function with the overflow is a recursive tree DFS with the following signature: `ll root(ll x, const vector<vector<pll>>& E, vector<ll>& P, vector<ll>& SZ) {`. The depth of the tree is `<= 800,000`, so I think the total required stack size AFAIK should be `8*800,000*4` bytes, around 30 MB. So it should be possible to get this to run.

I couldn't think of anything else to try. Any ideas? I'm on WSL version 1 in Ubuntu.

=========================================

Here is a simple repro. Save the following code as `ex.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
using ll = int64_t;

ll f(ll n) {
  if(n==0) { return 0LL; }
  return n + f(n-1);
}

int main() {
  struct rlimit rl;
  assert(0 == getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl));
  rl.rlim_cur = 3LL*1024*1024*1024;
  assert(0 == setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl));
  assert(0 == getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl));
  cerr << rl.rlim_cur << endl;

  cout << f(1e6) << endl;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++17 -Wl,-z,stack-size=1000000000 ex.cc -fsanitize=address && ./a.out` gives a stack overflow (also without `-fsanitize=address`). For me, it fails roughly 262,000 stack frames in.

Comment: *"so I think the total required stack size AFAIK should be 8*800,000*4 bytes,"* -- so no local variables in your function?

Comment: *"The depth of the tree is `<= 800,000`"* -- I just noticed that this refers to the depth of the tree, rather than the depth of your recursion. I guess we could assume that your function is not erroneously stuck in infinite recursion... Then again, assumptions and debugging often don't mix well... I'm getting closer to thinking there should be a [mre] (or at least the function, even if not the data to drive it) for this question to remove these nagging questions.

Comment: OK, I added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Cannot reproduce on a current WSL2/debian-testing.

Comment: I'm on WSL version 1 Ubuntu (the question wrongly stated WSL2; now fixed)

Comment: Upgrading to WSL2 fixed this...

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to WSL2 fixed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Either the setrlimit **or** `sudo prlimit --stack=unlimited --pid $$; ulimit -s unlimited` works (the linker option doesn't seem to matter).